# Host git repo on my VPS

Tags: server, repository, git, vps

I am trying to host a git repo on my VPS. However, I want to place the repo under the user home directory.

**Example**
http://DOMAIN_NAME/~askubuntu/gitrepo.git

I have apache2 installed which allows me to monitor the user files by accessing the above link.

I tried the following:

```
cd /home/askubuntu/public_html/
mkdir gitrepo.git
git --bare init
```

The above creates the directory `gitrepo.git` and adds files and folders for git (branch/ HEAD etc..)

My goal is to have several users clone my repo to their machines and contribute to it:

```
git clone askubuntu@DOMAIN_NAME:gitrepo.git
git push origin master
```

Right now if I try cloning the project it returns

```
fatal: 'gitrepo.git' does not appear to be a git repository
```

Any suggestions of what is missing, or any recommended tutorial/guide that you can share

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made the repository in `~/public_html/gitrepo.git`. So, if you use Git over SSH, the path would be relative your home directory:

```
git clone askubuntu@DOMAIN_NAME:public_html/gitrepo.git
```